# How can I change this animation transition to happen automatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, delay

Currently, my code allows the player to go to the next scene by clicking. I want to, however, make the fade out into the next scene animation automatic after 4 seconds. How can I do this?

I've tried looking up information, but nothing seems to work.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class LevelChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
float timer = 4f;
public Animator animator;
private int levelToLoad;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Invoke("FadeToLevel(1)", 2f);

    }
}

public void FadeToLevel (int levelIndex)
{
    levelToLoad = levelIndex;
    animator.SetTrigger("FadeBlack");
}

public void OnF`enter code here`adeComplete()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
}

}
```

The code works as intended, but I want the animation to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are aiming is to make an animation to play automatically when the player enters the new scene.

If that's the case, then you are looking for [the sceneLoaded() method from SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)

Also, [this discussion may be useful](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1295912/view.html)